# AngularJS: Button click and get button id name from directive function

Tags: angularjs

i have attached a directive with my button and want to get button names but directive is not working. i am new in angular so not being able to capture where the problems lies. please see my code and tell me the reason.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.directive('busybox',function(){
     return function(scope, element, attrs){
          element.click(function(){
               //element.parent().find('.main').append('<div>Some text</div>')
               alert('hello');
           })
      }
})
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/4o1zkbj1/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your directive code is not correct, it has to return object.

```
 return  {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on('click', function(){
        alert('clicked');
        });           
      }
    }
```

Also. Correct you directive name to `busyBox` (camel case)  and use `element.on('click', function(\\`

Working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sr5j9ja6/)

Comment: You said I need to return object but which object you talking about? Is that link function. How a function can be as object?

Comment: @Tridip: directive function return an object, and `link` is function property of it. [Read Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives)